# How to find the actions of the UIbuttons from the storyboard ?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have been given a prebuild set of storyboards. There are quite a few buttons in the storyboard. Is there a way of knowing that touching a particular button calls which method in which view controller ?

Comment: If my answer is correct make sure to mark it as the correct answer, if not, don't be afraid to ask for clarifications or expand your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you right clic on the button itself (and then probably expand the view that appears because it's too small usually ).

Or, select the button, and then clic on the little arrow on the top right, the latest button of all the inspectors, the " Connections inspector "

Comment: Ahhh! that was simple. Thanks!